# SharePoint conflict with same username in different domains

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory

We recently ran into a problem in which when we updated a user's photo in mysite, it automatically updated another user's profile with the same photo. On further researching, we found that both users having the same username but they are in different domains. for eg: domain1\user1 and domain2\user1.We have a connection to AD for both domain1 and domain2 and a trust established between the 2 domains.Any fixes for this issue other than changing the username of any of the user?

Comment: How did you establish trust between two domains. Just eager to learn that :)

Comment: I'm not really sure about this, so I won't post it as an answer, but have you tried to go to the User Profile Service applicaiton and there to "Setup My Sites". There is an option "Site Naming Format" where you could choose "Domain and user name (will not have conflicts)" - this is used for the naming of sites but maybe it will also be used for storage of user photos.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to set the profile picture user property direction to Import instead of Export, assuming user1 uploads the picture in SharePoint. On Export, the picture overwrites the AD profile picture. In order to change the profile picture (on Import) you have to change the profile picture in your AD (domain1 and domain2).